# How to update an entire sql column using python?

Tags: python, sql, sql-update

I want to update an entire column in a sql database. With the following command I can update a both the age and height of the person bob:

```
cursur.execute("UPDATE students SET age=10, height= 1.6 WHERE name='bob'")
```

But is there a way to fill in vectors for age, height and name, so that multiple values are updated simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a function:

```
def updateData(age, height, name):
    myQuery = "UPDATE students SET age=" + age + "  height=" + height +" WHERE name=" + name
    cursur.execute(myQuery)
```

you can use a for loop if you want to loop through array or any data.

Comment: Thanks. I actually wondered If it could with out a for loop.